# Consumer and context.watch in MultiProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying Flutter for the first time, and I am a little confused by the `MultiProvider` class.

The question is straightforward, but I didn't find an explanation:

> when should one use `Consumer` and when `context.watch`?

For instance, taking one of the examples apps I have found, I tried using two providers for two global states, the theme and the status of the app:

```
runApp(
  MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AppTheme()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AppStatus()),
  ],
  child: const MyApp()
  ));
```

Then the app widget accesses the theme with `Consumer`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppTheme>(
      builder: (context, appTheme, child) {
        // ...
```

As far as I understand, now all children widgets will inherit the provider. Is it right?

My home page, then, called by the `MyApp` class **does not** use `Consumer`, but `context.watch`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final appTheme = context.watch<AppTheme>();
  final appStatus = context.watch<AppStatus>();
  return NavigationView( 
    // ...
```

It works, don't get me wrong, but I just copied the row above my `appStatus`, so I don't really fully understand it. This is also due to another screen that I've concocted to access the `AppStatus` global state, but I use `Consumer`, [as suggested by the Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple):

```
class _ViewerState extends State<Viewer> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppStatus>(
      builder: (context, appStatus, child) {
        return ScaffoldPage.scrollable(
          header: const PageHeader(title: Text('Test')),
          children: [
            FilledButton(child: Text("Try ${appStatus.count}"), onPressed: (){ appStatus.increment(); debugPrint('pressed ${appStatus.count}'); }),
            FilledButton(child: Text("Reset"), onPressed: (){ appStatus.reset(); }),
          ]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have the feeling that I am misusing something here, and I do not really understand what's going on under the hood...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`context.watch<T>()` and `Consumer<T>` does the same thing. Most of the time `context.watch<T>()` is just more convenient. In some cases where `context` is not available `Consumer<T>` is useful.